# Подключение через socket

Tags: c#

Добрый вечер!

Не работает подключение через сокеты, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема?

Код:

```
IPHostEntry host = null;
host = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip_host);
foreach (IPAddress address in host.AddressList)
{
    IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(address, 1337);
    Socket samp = new Socket(ipe.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    samp.Connect(ipe);
    if (samp.Connected)
    {
        samp.Close();
        //Дальнейшее действие
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Ошибка: "Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера".

Ошибка, похоже, не в коде, а в настройках VPS'a. Но там, я добавил айпи в брандмауэр, но всё равно не работает.

Comment: А код, выполняющийся на другом компьютере (сервере) можете показать?

Comment: @Алексей Саровский, а такого кода нет. Разве он должен быть?

Comment: а куда вы тогда хотите подключиться? Кто Вам должен ответить? Погуглил - 1337 порт - неофициально (Википедия так пишет) - это порт p2p-программы WASTE. Вы на это рассчитывали (что ответит эта программа)? Или просто так выбрали. Если так, то ответить Вам некому.